# Android lambda expression settings

Tags: java, android, lambda, jack-toolchain

I want to use lambda expressions in my Android project, I followed the [Android guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html) to set up the Jack compiler and it did work.

However, the guide also mentions a known issue that the Jack compiler does not support instant run, and I found it is really time consuming to recompile all the Java files every time.

So, is there any other compiler that can generate intermediate class files, so that I do not have to recompile all the files every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is not official library by Google,
I recommend you **[retrolambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda)**. I think that retrolambda is easier and more simple than Jack Compiler.

Comment: That's great. Unlike the Jack compiler, I don't have to recompile the project every time using retrolambda.

Answer (score 1):

**Updates :**

Lambda Expression is now supported in Android Studio 3.0